# What (are there any) languages with only pass-by-reference?

Tags: programming-languages, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I was wondering. Are there languages that use *only* pass-by-reference as their eval strategy?

Comment: Sorry, only turing-complete languages. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what an "eval strategy" is, but Perl subroutine calls are pass-by-reference only.

```
sub change {
    $_[0] = 10;
}

$x = 5;
change($x);
print $x;  # prints "10"
change(0);  # raises "Modification of a read-only value attempted" error
```

Comment: Just putting a sutpid query here...is this idea of pass by value/reference is something dependent on the internal organization of a programming language or how it appears it to the programmer. I am asking this because most people say java emulates call-by-reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value and http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html
. But it appears as call by reference from programming point of view. Same way can we be sure that perl not using call by val in back??

Answer (score 1):

How about Brainfuck?

Comment: Fine, may very well be, but you will have to provide some evidence. I don't know all languages.

Comment: It has no functions, therefore its functions are only pass-by-reference.  :-P  Also, it is turing-complete.

Answer (score 1):

VB (pre .net), VBA & VBS *default* to ByRef although it can be overriden when calling/defining the sub or function.

Answer (score 1):

FORTRAN does; well, preceding such concepts as pass-by-reference, one should probably say that it uses pass-by-address; a FORTRAN function like:

```
INTEGER FUNCTION MULTIPLY_TWO_INTS(A, B)
INTEGER A, B
MULTIPLY_BY_TWO_INTS = A * B
RETURN
```

will have a C-style prototype of:

```
extern int MULTIPLY_TWO_INTS(int *A, int *B);
```

and you could call it via something like:

```
int result, a = 1, b = 100;

result = MULTIPLY_TWO_INTS(&a, &b);
```

Another example are languages that do not know function arguments as such but use stacks. An example would be Forth and its derivatives, where a function can change the variable space (stack) in whichever way it wants, modifying existing elements as well as adding/removing elements. "prototype comments" in Forth usually look something like

```
(argument list -- return value list)
```

and that means the function takes/processes a certain, not necessarily constant, number of arguments and returns, again, not necessarily a constant, number of elements. I.e. you can have a function that takes a number `N` as argument and returns `N` elements - preallocating an array, if you so like.

Comment: This does not demonstrate pass-by-reference. In the example you provide, `MULTIPLY_TWO_INTS` would have to modify `A` or `B`, and then we would have to see that the caller's version of `A` or `B` has changed after the call.