# What does the [REFERENCE] tag do in an argument declaration?

Tags: fortran, pass-by-reference

I am writing an custom callback function in Fortran for a piece of software (example [here](http://www.kxcad.net/RecurDyn/RecurDyn_Ver6.3/programmanual/user_Subroutines/User_subroutine/Contact_Force/Frotran%20example%20for%20contact%20force_USUB/Fortran_Ex.htm)) that includes the following argument declaration

```
SUBROUTINE CONTACT_FORCE(TIME,UPAR,NPAR,PEN,RVEL,JFLAG,IFLAG,RESULT)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT,C::CONTACT_FORCE
...
DOUBLE PRECISION RESULT[REFERENCE](6)   !Compiles ok
```

Which compiles fine with Compaq Visual Fortran 6. So my question is what does the `[REFERENCE]` tag do? I thought that Fortran [passes everything by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914181/what-are-there-any-languages-with-only-pass-by-reference/5261933#5261933) (and not by value). Of course there nothing in the compiler help about this, and searching online is difficult because the word reference is used so much with respect to Fortran that I don't know how to narrow it down.

**Edit** the above must be identical to

```
SUBROUTINE CONTACT_FORCE(TIME,UPAR,NPAR,PEN,RVEL,JFLAG,IFLAG,RESULT)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT,C::CONTACT_FORCE
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE::RESULT
...
DOUBLE PRECISION RESULT(6)   !Compiles ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming MS products here. Fortran can be made to pass by value or by reference if the `C` or `STDCALL` attribute is used. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa294334(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: So this is the same as adding the declaration `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: RESULT` instead?