# How to make Fortran program with [REFERENCE] compatible with gfortran?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I am working on compiling an old piece of Fortran code written sometime in the early 2000s.  In this code base there are functions designed to interface with C code and have the following structure:

```
SUBROUTINE F_LIB_FOO(MY_VAR)
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT,STDCALL :: F_LIB_FOO
   REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: MY_VAR [REFERENCE]
   LIB_FOO(MY_VAR) !This calls the function implemented internally
```

However, when I try to compile it using `gfortran 4.4.7` I get the following error

```
REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: MY_VAR  [REFERENCE]
                             1
Error: Syntax error in data declaration at (1)
```

My belief is that `REFERENCE` indicates that the `MY_VAR` is passed by reference.  However, I can't find any examples that use this sort of syntax.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560927/what-does-the-reference-tag-do-in-an-argument-declaration) answer, this syntax is supported in Visual Studios. I want to know if there is a similar way to do this in a Linux machine and if there isn't, how can I change the code to compile with `gfortran` and have the same functionality.

Comment: It is sort of implied there that you can just delete it, but to understand that you must know what STDCALL is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the linked answer says, the `[REFERENCE]` attribute is a highly non-standard thing that changes the behaviour for [STDCALL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) calling conventions. Stdcall is the standard calling convention for the Microsoft Win32 API and for Open Watcom C++.

You can safely delete it for Linux programs and for 64-bit Windows as well.

For situations (Win32), where it might be necessary, GCC uses `!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL`, but I am not sure how to specify `REFERENCE` there.